# How to get the survey List from surveygizmo API in the Postman?(Trial Version)

Tags: javascript, php, surveyjs

I want to get a list of the survey from SurveyGizmo API itself but it's not working for Me. For valid tokens also it always returns an error code is 401.

Alchemer :Version 5

[https://api.alchemer.com/v5/survey?api_token="token"&api_token_secret="token"](https://api.alchemer.com/v5/survey?api_token=%22token%22&api_token_secret=%22token%22)

Response: {"result_ok":false,"code":401,"message":"Invalid api_token or api_token_secret supplied"}

Comment: You have to assume that the error message is right, 1000 of others use this API therefore check you are using the right token or secret

Comment: It's a valid token only.I tried with another account also.Same 401 response.

Comment: How about the token secret

Comment: token secret also  valid as per surveygizmo dashboard(Just copy and pasted).I'm using trial version

Comment: Well if the error message is lying to you I dont know quite where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change the region while registering. The trial version is currently supporting US-region

Comment: Have you made API calls using R?

Answer (score 1):

Late to this question but I just started using Alchemer (formerly SurveyGizmo) and the API access as shown below.  You need to create an API app on Alchemer's site first.

```
# get responses from a survey:
# be sure to update the URL with your survey id number
library(ODataQuery)
s1res <-   ODataQuery::retrieve_data(
url = paste0(
  "https://api.alchemer.com/v5/survey/yourIdNumberHere/surveyresponse?api_token=", 
  api_token,
  "&api_token_secret=",
  apiSecretKey     )  )


s1data <-   s1res$data # yields a list for each respondent named "survey_data"

df<- tidyr::unnest(s1data$survey_data) 
table(df$answer10)  # check responses for one question

# remove unnecessary vars using `dplyr`
df2<-df %>% select(starts_with("question") | starts_with("answer")) %>% select(-contains("_id"))

# make column names from the first row of values
q_text<-df2 %>% select(starts_with("question")) %>% slice_head(n=1) %>% as.character()
df3<-df2 %>% select(starts_with("answer"))
colnames(df3)<-str_replace_all(q_text," ","") # assign new col names; check!
```